# php not executed when loading file via js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In a bootstrap accordion I am loading a php file when the accordion is being expanded. However, the php statements are not executed in that file, only the static html content in that file is shown.

The js looks like this.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
if (collapseHouse && !house_loaded) {
        collapseHouse.addEventListener('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            if (!house_loaded) {    
                phpFile = 'mhouse_content.php';
                $('#house-load-div').load('/presentation/mobile/' + phpFile);
                house_loaded = true;
            }
            var scrollOffset = mainAccordion.scrollTop + collapseHouse.parentNode.offsetTop
            window.scroll({
                top: scrollOffset,
                left: 0, 
                behavior: 'smooth'
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: "*php statements are not executed in that file*" - What do you mean by this? Is the PHP actually visible in the returned HTML? Did you check the network request tab if any errors occured?

Comment: To be honest, not sure how to see this. I am using Safari and there I only see the initial html in the source code, not the code added by js. With not executed I mean that `<p>abc</p> <?php echo 'def';?>` only shows `abc`

Comment: Does your `.php` file output correct if you call it via the address bar, not via jquery?

Comment: Open your browser's Developer Tools, then load the page with the JS in it, then see if there are any errors in the Console or Network areas. If you're going to write JS and ajax code, you need to understand the basics of how to debug it

Comment: @brombeer: yes, ADyson: no warnings, errors etc. So I understand, typically it should process php when dynamically loading the page

Comment: Apologies, found my mistake. When I `include` other php files, I can directly use my existing functions and variables. When loading the file with js, I cannot. Unfortunately `<?php echo $textHouse[1];?>` failed silently without a warning that the variable is not declared.

Comment: Are you sure it failed silently? In the Network tool if you see the request to the PHP file, you can then click on that request and see the raw Response in another tab. That might show the warning message. Or if not, check your PHP log file. You should always have PHP configured to show errors and warnings either in the output (for a dev environment) or in a file (more secure and user-friendly for a live environment).

Comment: `When loading the file with js, I cannot`...why? PHP doesn't know or care whether it was invoked via JS or some other method. You can still use `include` or `require` exactly the same as any other time. It's unclear what issue you actually had with that, or why, without more context.

Comment: If I include a php file in the initial build, I do not have to re-include previously included files (or initialized variables). With a php file loaded afterwards, however, I have to re-include/require the files . That is what I missed. Possibly it only silently failed for me - this is a side project and I am quite struggling with PHP (actually I wonder that most php pages in the Internet work so flawlessly ;-) ). Anyhow, thanks for the help!

Comment: "_it only silently failed for me_" Do you have error reporting turned on? [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1)

Comment: `With a php file loaded afterwards, however, I have to re-include/require the files`....well it's a completely  separate HTTP request to the server,  which then invokes a completely separate instance of PHP, to run a completely separate execution of the PHP script requested. It has absolutely nothing to do with any PHP script which ran in order to load the page initially. That is an important thing to realise when using AJAX requests.

Comment: Thanks, now PHP errors are turned on... @ADyson yes that is what I realized and what makes absolutely sense - after realizing it